# how to hiden the unncessary lines or edges on the same complete plane when pyqtgraph displays a STL file

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I found a STL viewer program using pyqtgraph from [STLViewer](https://github.com/Be4rR/STLViewer)
[pyqtgraph document](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style.html) 
the key parameters are set as

```
# color is a tuple in the form RGBA  (0.4,0.9,0.6,1)`
mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawEdges=True, drawFaces=True,  shader='balloon',color= (0.4,0.9,0.6,1))
```

a stl file appearance displays as the following

[image]

This appearance is not I want, since it displays many edges even though on the same complete plane.

and if set `drawEdges=False` then it displays as

[image]

However, the concrete edges I can touch are also hidden, this is not I want too.

What I want is like this

[image]

this is painted by pyVTK

the main  program is

```
import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()  # maps polygonal data to graphics primitives
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
actor_0 = vtk.vtkLODActor()
actor_0.SetMapper(mapper)
actor_0.SetScale(1000, 1000, 1000)
actor_0.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(0.4,0.9,0.6)
actor_0.GetProperty().SetDiffuse(.8)
actor_0.GetProperty().SetSpecular(.5)
actor_0.GetProperty().SetSpecularColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
actor_0.GetProperty().SetSpecularPower(30.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the surface based on the normal vector by specifying the shader. `viewNormalColor` seems to fit what you're looking for among the builtin shaders.

[Using viewNormalColor shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlIe0.png)

```
mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawFaces=True, drawEdges=False, shader='viewNormalColor', glOptions='opaque')
```

There's an example code of using builtin shaders.
https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/examples/GLshaders.py

But this is too flashy. So, I did a search and found that it is possible to add a custom shader.

https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/opengl/shaders.py

Here is the code for adding a custom shader. I don't know much about shaders, but I modified the `viewNormalColor` shader to make the surface green.

```
gl.shaders.Shaders.append(gl.shaders.ShaderProgram('myShader', [
    gl.shaders.VertexShader("""
            varying vec3 normal;
            void main() {
                // compute here for use in fragment shader
                normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
                gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
                gl_BackColor = gl_Color;
                gl_Position = ftransform();
            }
        """),
    gl.shaders.FragmentShader("""
            varying vec3 normal;
            void main() {
                vec4 color = gl_Color;
                color.x = 0.0;
                color.y = (normal.y + 1.0) * 0.5;
                color.z = 0.0;
                gl_FragColor = color;
            }
        """)
]))
```

Then pass the shader name.

```
mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawFaces=True,
                         drawEdges=False, shader='myShader', glOptions='opaque')
```

[Using myShader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvPH.png)

I hope you will find it useful.